# Using AutoMapper in repository classlibrary

Tags: asp.net, .net, repository, automapper

I would like to use AutoMapper for the first time..

```
    public static class AutoMapperWebConfig
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.AddProfile(new WebConfigurationProfile()); 
        });
    }
}

public class WebConfigurationProfile : Profile
{
    public WebConfigurationProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<PovUsers, PovUserView>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Name, m => m.MapFrom(p => p.PovUserName))
            .ForMember(x => x.User, m => m.MapFrom(p => p.PovUserId));
    }
}
```

I have several project in solution. One Web project and one class library (Repository) which works with EntityFramework DB Context. AutoMapper is initializing in Global.asax.

Is there a way to use this Mapper in the Repository. Now i get an error (Missing map) when I try to do this:

```
        public IQueryable<PovUserView> GetSet() {
        return this.dbSet.ProjectTo<PovUserView>(); ;
    }
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your Mapping Configuration and Profiles in a class in repository project, like this:

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<GeneralMapping>();
            cfg.AddProfile<CustomerMapping>();
        });
    }
}
```

and call static method of Configure from any web application's Global.asax that you want to use repositories.

Comment: Awesome. That solve my problem.. Many thanks to you!